# Powershell Vulnerability Assessment in SQL

Tags: sql, powershell, security

Im trying to use  [powershell cmdlets for managing SQL Vulnerability Assessments.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlsecurity/powershell-cmdlets-for-managing-sql-vulnerability-assessments)
As output i need a JSON file which i can import into SSMS.
The only cmdlet which can generate JSON file is Export-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentBaselineSet. However as output it generates something like one single line with one single baseline and it doesnt contain JSON hierarchy which can be red by SSMS, like:

```
{"Version":"1.0","RuleBaselines":[{"RuleId":"VA2109","Properties":{"Severity":null,"ExpectedResults":[["xp_instance_regread","public"],["xp_regread","public"]],"UpdatedTime":"2020-10-01T10:28:59.5565389Z","SizeInBytes":82}}]}
```

The code i used to generate this is:

```
 $scanResult = Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MainInstance" -Database some_database
 $failedResults = @{}
 $scanResult.Results.GetEnumerator() | Where {$_.Value.Status -eq "Failed"} | foreach {$failedResults[$_.Key] = $_.Value }
 $failedCheckResults = $failedResults["VA2109"].QueryResults
 $baseline = New-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentBaseline -SecurityCheckId "VA2109" -ExpectedResult $failedCheckResults
 $baselineSet = New-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentBaselineSet -Baselines $baseline
 $baselineSet | Export-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentBaselineSet -FolderPath ".\baseline.json"
```

Can someone please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: What would a valid JSON document look like?

Comment: I upload JSON file(generated by SSMS) in this link: https://gofile.io/d/6ldwpp

Comment: Have you tried exporting the scan results manually? `$scanResult |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 7 |Set-Content -Path .\scanResult.json`

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen, thank you for helping. Please check for file from SSMS: https://gofile.io/d/z1VMpJ and from Powershell: https://gofile.io/d/AHUptR Unfortuantelly the structure is different and SSMS doesnt read json file from convertto-json cmdlet.